# How can I write server side code in Perl for the WWW?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl programming. How can I use it instead of PHP? In Xampp or PHP we have "htdocs" to store our .php files but how could I save my .pl file?

When I try to open a .pl through localhost the whole file was downloadable, unlike in php when we open a .php, the php code is executed.

Comment: At least give your question a relevant title. Right now it gives others no clue about the question.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest option is to configure your web server to support CGI and then write your Perl to follow the CGI protocol (the [CGI module](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) is helpful for this). You can configure servers to execute any file with a .pl extension if you wish.

Slightly more complicated, but more flexible, is [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/). This is a set of middleware that you can hook up to a web server in a variety of ways (e.g. FastCGI or mod_perl) for better performance. This also gives some nice debugging options. There is an [advent calendar style guide](http://advent.plackperl.org/2009/12/day-1-getting-plack.html) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

XoR has already mentioned it, but I want to reiterate: [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us)! It has a templating engine that lets you intermix Perl code in the HTML, however you can do most of the heavy lifting inside the application itself. Mojolicious also includes (several) built-in web servers  (one for testing, one for production), which are far easier to use than Apache.

Easy to install: just install `Mojolicious` using `cpan` (or other).

Write a basic script: ( a simple Hello World ):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/(:name)' => {name => 'World'} => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->render('index');
};

app->start;

__DATA__

@@ index.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
  <title> Hello <%= $name %> </title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello <%= $name %>
</body>
</html>
```

And run: `morbo myapp.pl`

Comment: Note that __DATA__ doesn't seem to work on my perl XAMPP install on Windows, and that you must put index.html.ep in it's own file in a templates directory http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite#External_templates

Comment: What happens if you run it through Strawberry Perl, or activestate rather than XAMPP? Is there any info on which Perl is included with XAMPP?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be easy to find out what type of perl XAMPP ships with. There's nothing on the XAMPP site that mentions what type. perl -v just says 5.10

http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Win32_Distributions#XAMPP_.2B_Perl-Extension

Comment: If you can, give StrawberryPerl a shot. Mojolicious doesn't need (most of) the other parts of XAMPP anyway, it has the built-in servers, so you don't need apache.

Answer (score 0):

From a naive approach, it sounds like your web server isn't configured properly; it should be interpreting the file, not handing it out.

Out of curiosity, why are you using Perl for web stuff if you know PHP? I thought I read an article a while back stating that PHP was faster than Perl when used for displaying webpages.

Comment: First benchmark I found on Google suggested that Perl was significantly faster than PHP. (No idea how representative of real world stuff that is though). You might have found something comparing CGI to mod_php; CGI has a massive start up cost associated with each request.

Comment: Even in CGI mode and using DBIx::Class ORM, Perl can be fast.

Comment: For greater than 90% of webpages, speed is pretty much immaterial.  Are your early experiments going to be handling 1000s of hits a minute?  Not likely.  Any benchmark that naively compares "Perl" to "PHP" on a web serving basis is not worth the bits its composed of.  There are so many issues regarding webserver choice and configuration for each environment that any statement in general is fatuous, at best.

Comment: As to "Why learn to use Perl when you already know PHP?"  Jeepers, man! Why eat a potato when you have already know and love yams?  Furthermore, besides learning and exploration, there are other reasons to learn: Work or School assignments perhaps.  Maybe he heard good things about Perl, maybe it's all the libraries.  But really, sometimes the journey is more important than reaching the destination--maybe User9834894389342 is trying to set that up for him/her/itself.

Answer (score 0):

See ["Configuring Apache" on Strawberry wiki](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Configuring_Apache).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with Perl5 web development it is usefull to start with CGI, but that
is not necesity.

There is [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) module. You could look at how HTTP works
and how Apache or whatever server you use calls your CGI program. Good start is using this
script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                                             

use strict;                                                                     
use warnings;                                                                   

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";                                            
print "<html>";                                                                                           
print "<body>";                                                                 
print "<table>";                                                                
for my $var_name (keys %ENV) {                                                  
  print "<tr>";                                                                 
  print "<td>$var_name</td>";                                                   
  print "<td>$ENV{$var_name}</td>", "\n";                                       
  print "</tr>"                                                                 
}                                                                               
print "</table>";                                                               
print "</body>";                                                                
print "</html>";
```

Then looking at variables like "REQUEST_URI", "REQUEST_METHOD" and "QUERY_STRING", you can
get idea what CGI module is doing in background.

It's important to know that your script must be at directory that is set up to run cgi
scripts, like:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi_bin/ /var/cgi_bin/                                             

<Directory /var/cgi_bin/>                                                       
  Options +ExecCGI                                                                                        
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl                                                
</Directory>
```

And file have to be executable by any user that runs your server (eg. Apache2), and readable.

Also after this you can look at modern toolkits like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) & [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/). I recomend
you mojolicious. Also there is web framework called [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/).

About frameworks, Catalyst is long time here and it works, but it kind of took some kraft with it. This is tried to be fixed with new frameworks like mojolicious. Mojolicious don't
have almost no external CPAN dependencies.